# PHP 7.2 - Parse zipped xml stream without saving as .zip

Tags: php, unzip

I receive a MIME stream that contains a plain xml file and zipped xml file:

```
-MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_A0162A4E6FCACE7B6C1578623716971702885
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:A0162A4E6FCACE7B6C1578623716971702886>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Response><Status>OK</Status><UUID>A0162A4E6FCACE7B6C1578623716971702886</UUID></Response>
--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_A0162A4E6FCACE7B6C1578623716971702885
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <urn:uuid:8D7801E6D98280EACC1578624071046>

PK    ÇŽ)Pž¶È®  Ø    A0162A4E6FCACE7B6C1578623716971702886.xmlUT
....
....
    
--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_A0162A4E6FCACE7B6C1578623716971702885--
```

I can easily extract and parse the plain xml file directly in memory, but I've not found the way to do the same with the zipped file:

is there a way to parse the zipped xml file without saving it as a file first?

something like

`$xml=simplexml_load_string ('zip://'.$zipped_xml_substring);`
or
`$xml=simplexml_load_string (unzip($zipped_xml_substring));`

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked [zlib](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) wrapper (it requires [ZIP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php))?

In comments on that page you'll find few examples of usage. I will post two of them below which I think might be relevant for you:

```
$fp = fopen('zip://./foo.zip#bar.txt', 'r');
if( $fp ){
    while( !feof($fp) ){
        echo fread($fp, 8192);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

or using `php://input` input

```
file_get_contents("compress.zlib://php://input");
```

Comment: the file_get_contents solution could be interesting.. but I do not have an input but is a substring of the payload of a CURL response: how can modify the command?